# The connection is closed before the keepAliveDurationNs is reached

Tags: okhttp

In okhttp's code, `connection.idleAtNs` has been assigned in `releaseConnectionNoEvents()` method,

```kotlin
    internal fun releaseConnectionNoEvents(): Socket? {
        val connection = this.connection!!
        connection.assertThreadHoldsLock()
    
        val calls = connection.calls
        val index = calls.indexOfFirst { it.get() == this@RealCall }
        check(index != -1)
    
        calls.removeAt(index)
        this.connection = null
    
        if (calls.isEmpty()) {
          connection.idleAtNs = System.nanoTime()
          if (connectionPool.connectionBecameIdle(connection)) {
            return connection.socket()
          }
        }
    
        return null
      }
```

but why Re-assignment here

```kotlin
        private fun pruneAndGetAllocationCount(connection: RealConnection, now: Long): Int {
        connection.assertThreadHoldsLock()
    
        val references = connection.calls
        var i = 0
        while (i < references.size) {
          val reference = references[i]
    
          if (reference.get() != null) {
            i++
            continue
          }
    
          // We've discovered a leaked call. This is an application bug.
          val callReference = reference as CallReference
          val message = "A connection to ${connection.route().address.url} was leaked. " +
              "Did you forget to close a response body?"
          Platform.get().logCloseableLeak(message, callReference.callStackTrace)
    
          references.removeAt(i)
          connection.noNewExchanges = true
    
          // If this was the last allocation, the connection is eligible for immediate eviction.
          if (references.isEmpty()) {
            connection.idleAtNs = now - keepAliveDurationNs
            return 0
          }
        }
    
        return references.size
      }
```

If assign a value here, it may appear that the connection is removed as soon as it becomes idle.

Comment: Please, make your post more readable by using ie <code> tags. Posts that separate your words from example offer visual distinction and will be read and answered more quickly. Well done getting your question out there!

Comment: OK，I have edit it.

Answer (score 0):

The pruneAndGetAllocationCount method is called as part of a cleanup task.  At the point you have linked to, the code has already logged a warning about a connection leak.  The code releases that connection then considders the connection to be immediately available for release.

If you have concerns about the code, consider making a test case that shows what you would propose changing the code to, it might be possible to improve it.

If it's affecting you because of leaked connections, you should instead fix the bug in the application code.

```
          // We've discovered a leaked call. This is an application bug.
          val callReference = reference as CallReference
          val message = "A connection to ${connection.route().address.url} was leaked. " +
              "Did you forget to close a response body?"
```